# Jquery array not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a menu and on click menu i want to filter my div according to my menu data attribute value
**Here is Sample of my code**

```
<li class="menu" data-cat="flower">
<li class="menu" data-cat="car">



<div class="item" data-item="lily"></div>
<div class="item" data-item="Audy"></div>
<div class="item" data-item="BMW"></div>
<div class="item" data-item="sunflower"></div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('.menu').on("click",function(e){
    var menu=$(this).attr("data-cat");
    /*
    console.log(menu) ; // displaying car
    var items=$('.item');
    for(var i; i<items.length;i++) {
        console.log(items[i].attr('data-items'))
        /*
        console.log(items[i].length) ----- > length not define
        console.log(items[i].data('item') ----- > data is not a function
        */ 
    }
```

on `console.log(items[i])` will displaying `<div class="item" data-item="BMW"></div>`

[image: my orignal screenshot]

Comment: where is `attr("data-flower")` defined?

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, `items[i]` is a simple javascript object, what you need to do in order to use `data()` function, then you'll need to convert it to jQuery object like this `$(items[i])`.

```
$('.menu').on("click",function(e){
    var menu = $(this).attr("data-flower");
    var items = $('.item');
    for(var i; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log( $(items[i]).data('item') );
    }
});
```

Comment: i thnk you haven't notice this line `console.log(items[i].data('item') ----- > data is not a function`

Comment: @codeBloger I updated my answer, you'll understand why it did not work.